# Java code to login to website which contains emailId in page and password in another page

Tags: java

I want to write a Java application, which can login to a website For example, www.tumblr.com/login. Basically this web page asks for an email address on the first page and then would take the user to the next page to enter the password.

Can someone please help me with a sample Java code for this problem?

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Robert. My code looks similar to what is mentioned here http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-use-httpurlconnection-post-data-to-web-server/139. But this code is useful only when the website expects username and password in the same page. But the website which i am trying to login [www.tumblr.com/login] expects only username in the first page and only when the username is verified, then i am prompted to enter the password. My question is how i link these two pages?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

```
public static String executePost(String targetURL, String urlParameters) {
  HttpURLConnection connection = null;

  try {
    //Create connection
    URL url = new URL(targetURL);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", 
        Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");  

    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    //Send request
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
        connection.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.close();

    //Get Response  
    InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder(); // or StringBuffer if Java version 5+
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
      response.append(line);
      response.append('\r');
    }
    rd.close();
    return response.toString();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
  } finally {
    if (connection != null) {
      connection.disconnect();
    }
  }
```

Code example found [here](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-use-httpurlconnection-post-data-to-web-server/139)

Comment: Thanks for response. But the website expects only username is the first page, only if the username is verified by the website, then only i am prompted for the password.